Why Angular component Null or not initialized after ngOnInit?
Hey so I am trying to pre-populate my signature pad if the user wishes to edit a form in my app.
This is my code for pre-populating:
 prePopulateLocalSignatures(captainSignature:any,OfficerSignature:any){
    if(this.signaturePad1 && this.signaturePad2){
      this.signaturePad1.clear();
      this.signaturePad1.fromDataURL(captainSignature);
      this.signaturePad2.clear();
      this.signaturePad2.fromDataURL(OfficerSignature);
      console.log('SHOULDA WORKED?!?!')
    }
    else{
      console.log('DIDNT WORK!?!?!')
    }
  }

I call this function in ngAfterViewIniti() to ensure the signaturepads are initialized. These are the signaturepads:
 @ViewChild('captainsSignPad') public signaturePad1!: SignaturePad;
 @ViewChild('boardingOfficerSignPad') public signaturePad2!: SignaturePad;

I have tried using a set-timeout but that still didnt work:
  ngAfterViewInit(){
     setTimeout(() => this.prePopulateLocalSignatures(this.data.vsl_captain_signature, this.data.boarding_officers_signature), 0);
  }    


Did you add the component in AppModule -> Declaration array?

@Avilon no, should I do that? Also I just found a quick fix where I wait 2 seconds then execute the function lol

Please share your html.

Does this answer your question? Angular 2 @ViewChild annotation returns undefined

@Teahana, remember that if you have your component under a *ngIf="condition", you should first makes condition true and (enclosed in a setTimeout without time) ask about the component. NOTE: if the condition is fullfilled in a subscribe function, you should call to prePopulateLocalSignatures inside subscribe function.

Where is the html part that is supposed to have #signaturePad1 and #signaturePad2 attribs?
